# TextBox trigger for IsEnabled

Tags: wpf, textbox, styles

I want to change my `TextBox` `Background` color while my control `IsEnable = false`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00ffffff"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But it seems that this not effect at all and now my `Backgroung` color is `transparent` and my `Watermark` (i am using MahApps) is missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BackgroundColor of a disabled TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957509/backgroundcolor-of-a-disabled-textbox)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3752517/2470362

Answer (score 1):

You have set the opacity part (first 2 digits) of the HEX colour to transparent (00).

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffffff"/>
```